# Drop rows based on value of aggregated field when using groupby function

Tags: pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a dataframe:

```
Code   Type   Flag    Value
 ab     MAS    A        1
 ab     MAS    B        1
 cd     FF4    A        2
 cd     FF4    B        2
 xy     67G    A        90
 xy     67G    B        90
```

I need to drop rows when I groupby the `Code`, `Type` and `Value` columns where the `Flag` value is `B`.

Is there a way to drop rows based on the aggregated field in the groupby syntax?

`df = df.groupby(['Code', 'Type', 'Value'])['Flag' != 'B']` This code is probably very wrong but its just for explanation purposes.

So this is the output:

```
Code   Type   Flag    Value
 ab     MAS    A        1
 cd     FF4    A        2
 xy     67G    A        90
```

Comment: I think filter per groups is not encessary, only use `df = df[df['Flag'] != 'B']`

Comment: Dropping aggregated rows based on a field isn't equal to just drop all the rows with "Flag = B"?